# How do I burn an ISO image to a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

What is the best way to burn an ISO image onto a USB flash drive?

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but to make your ISO "bootable" on Windows: http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Comment: Could you clarify if you want it bootable or just to extract the contents?

Comment: The answers on this question are better than the other one. The other question should be closed. 38k views vs 2k views. This is the question people have.

Comment: I think this question is not really a duplicate. The other refers to making the USB bootable, whereas this asks for a sector-by-sector copy of any binary data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For some variants of Linux, [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#features) does this without any extra configuration or work.

Comment: well, the only bad thing is, it changes some of the screens
and I'm not sure if it works everywhere

Comment: Another option is usb-creator-gtk, which is what I used in order to install Linux on my netbook.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the ISO image, I recommend [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) for anything Windows.

For Linux distributions, [see Anonymous' answer](https://superuser.com/questions/87124/burn-iso-to-usb-flash-drive/87127#87127).

Comment: badam-PISH. I should upvote this just for the punchline ;p

Comment: I don't see anything in WinToFlash that lets you select an ISO to use

Comment: WinToFlash is completely adware ridden. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Chrome blocks the download.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) command to "burn" an ISO image to a USB drive from the command line:

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Change `/dev/sdb` to the mount point of the USB drive.

Be careful, as this will destroy the original contents of the USB drive.

Additionally, if the ISO is bootable (such as in installer image) then the USB drive will boot the same way.

Comment: This does only work with specially crafted ISO images.

Comment: Do you have a windows version for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and just extract the contents onto the USB drive.

When extracted, you'll see the same contents you would if you browsed to the disc.

Comment: But will 7-zip make it boot-able?

Comment: No, probably not. You might want to put that in your question when you migrate it to Superuser. Making it bootable will require some additional steps.

Comment: This answer is no good. An ISO is more than just a file archive.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "burn" an ISO image to a USB flash drive.

If you want a bootable USB from an ISO image, there are a couple of things you need to do

1. Create a [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) partition on the USB drive (perferably, the first partition)
2. Mount the ISO image to access its contents
3. Copy the contents of the ISO image to the partition you just created.
4. You need the [SYSLINUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX) utility to make it bootable

Comment: You can "burn" an ISO to a flash drive, byte-by-byte. Maybe just not with windows ;)