# Tools to create a bootable USB stick from a bootable CD

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

Is there any tool to create a bootable USB stick from any bootable CD? Like I want to create a USB stick from [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive and http://superuser.com/questions/87124/burn-iso-to-usb-flash-drive-closed

Comment: "i'm still searching for one generic tool.........not specific to Win/Lin" generic tool for what? to create a bootable USB stick? just get the latest version of UBCD, all you need is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any tool to create a bootable USB stick from any bootable CD? Like I want to create a USB stick from Ultimate Boot CD.

Yes, and it is included in Ultimate Boot CD.

**[Quote](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)**:

> New! Run Ultimate Boot CD from your
>   USB memory stick
>
> - A script on the CD prepares your USB memory stick so that it can be
>     used on newer machines that supports
>     booting from USB devices. You can
>     access the same tools as you would
>     from the CD version.

Comment: This is for running the UltimateBootCD from USB not for running any bootable CD from USB.

Comment: @SoMoS - "I want to create a USB stick from ultimatebootcd"

Comment: @Molly: the header says "IS there any tool to create a bootable USB from any bootable CD"

Comment: @SoMoS - i tend to read the question before i answer, not only the header. you probably don't do the latter properly before quoting, i don't see the word ANY in the question :P

Comment: @Molly: LOL, really funny because the word is there :D:D:D I just copied and pasted the question. Check it out please. LOL. Reading is one of the things I do best :P

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do which works *most* (but not all, before I get corrected) of the time is to simply mark the drive as active (In disk management) and then copy all the contents of the CD to the USB drive (including system and hidden files).

Comment: won't work, you'll have to write the bootsector to the USB stick.

Comment: ... Before you edited your answer, your link pretty much said the same thing as my answer?...

Comment: Windows-based bootable USB drives, you'll need to add the bootmgr compatible code with bootsect.exe, then you can simply copy an entire Windows CD/DVD to the USB drive

Comment: certainly not, the older tutorial i posted before involved SYSLINUX to prepare the drive. http://www.getusb.info/ultimate-boot-cd-from-a-usb-pen-drive/

Comment: i'm still searching for one generic tool.........not specific to Win/Lin...it can be free or commercial...no issues

Answer (score 0):

[UNetbootin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin) would do the trick with pretty much any [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD).

Comment: read my question : "from any bootable CD" ........ would it work with a Win & CD?

Comment: hmm, any linux based one. Windows won't boot off a USB that easily- for windows installers there's pe2usb, or methods for windows vista and 7 such as this http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive/ . there's no universal way tho