# Bootable disk ? how can I create them?

Tags: software-rec, livecd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to create bootable USB from bootable CD](https://superuser.com/questions/88220/tools-to-create-bootable-usb-from-bootable-cd)

hi
My friend today gave me a bootable cd that have lots of bootable applications
is there a program a simple one to create such thing (I've heard about GRUB but :-) ) don't understand a word is there a program that generate bootable disks ( just fill some text boxes and link ISOs and stuff ( as creating the autorun menus ).

thanx

Comment: Unetbootin is great, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Making-a-GRUB-bootable-CD_002dROM.html