# Making a bootable pendrive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

How can put image (iso) and flat binary on pendrive to make it bootable ?
For example I am writing short system in assembler. How can I put it into pendrive instead of floppy disk?