# Install windows xp from USB using the iso image

Tags: windows-xp, installation, iso-image, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

I've got the windows xp ISO image on my computer and i want to install it on a computer without cdrom. The only way to do it is using usb flash drive.

I don't know how to do it - i need to burn the iso to usb, make the usb bootable, install windows xp from the usb onto the hardrive (the usb should just replace the standard windows install disc).

How to do it ?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/66948/place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 1):

there are a few tools that can easy do it all for you. try have a look on http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-vista-or-xp-usb-flashpen-drive-with-a-single-click-must-try/