# Windows 7 Ultimate files to Iso

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, dvd, iso-image

So i had copied my windows 7 files from an installation disc to a flash disk which i had made bootable to format a mini laptop with no DVD drive, then by mistake broke the installation disc but still have the files in the flash disc, i want to burn them into another disk. Have tried burning them as data but wont work in some systems...so how can i get to create a bootable disc / disc iso image?

Comment: *I rily need help ASAP* --- This really sounds a little bit rudely. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert flash drive to Windows installation CD](http://superuser.com/questions/144914/how-to-convert-flash-drive-to-windows-installation-cd)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=Download) which is maybe a little bit more straightforward than poweriso to work with. Be careful though not to install bloatware that comes with the installer.

Using Imgburn, you can easily create a new image from the files and folders on your usb drive. Then you can burn this image to your disc:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an official microsoft downloads

Windows 7 Ultimate x86 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24394.iso
Windows 7 Ultimate X64 SP1 (bootable)
http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24395.iso

Download burn to DVD and DONE.  It even has SP1 built-in

Answer (score 0):

Use the software Power Iso. It is not free. But the trial version is enough to accomplish your task. Install Poweriso. Plug in the usb. In the options, it has an option to create iso from USB. I have used it before. I didnt remember the exact menu and cant put screenshots now as i am in a linux machine now.