# Write bootable ISO to USB drive

Tags: usb, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

Okay, existing answers list programs I do not want to use. I know that it's possible using only basic UNIX tools because I've done it. I know that I want to copy the iso to the pendrive using `dd`, but what do I do before that? I assume I need to make the drive bootable. How do I do it (in (g)parted perhaps)?