# How do I upgrade Intel SSD firmware from USB?

Tags: boot, ssd, firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

Ok, here's the thing. I have one of those Intel 320 SSD drives that is prone to suddenly shrink to 8 MB in size. Two days ago, Intel released a firmware fix that takes care of this issue.

They supplied an ISO-file that they suggest you burn to CD-ROM and boot from. I don't have a CD- or DVD-drive, so I'm hoping to be able to install this from a USB stick. I've been trying to find a way to boot from a USB-stick, but so far without luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was in the same situation using Windows.  The other question isn't actually the same because it's asking about Windows/Linux installation ISOs.  The firmware update ISO contains a boot sector that must be preserved when copying onto your USB stick.  I tried UNetbootin as suggested, and, of course, nothing happened when it tried to launch the updater.  I ended up putting the ISO onto my USB stick using my own method.  I opened the ISO with 7-Zip, extracted the `Bootable_2.88M.img` file in the `[BOOT]` folder, and used Cygwin's `dd` utility to copy the raw bootable IMG file onto the USB stick.