# How to write precompilled image to USB flash drive from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have FreeBSD installation image for an USB memory stick, Windows 7 x64 desktop and server hardware nearby. And no CD drive at all for years.

Under Windows XP x86 you can use many solutions such as dd(Cygwin), dd(native), flashnul and many others (see links below). But they are not work under Windows 7 x64 with administrative rights. See official [info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448) from MS for information about this

Possible solutions:

1. In BSD/Solaris/Mac OS X/Linux this is dd(1). I have no BSD/Linux/etc
2. UNetBootin. MemStick with Linux works but doesn't with FreeBSD. I have no success with it from Windows XP too.
3. Use Acronis/Daemon Tools/Nero/UltraISO and etc. - it may be works but they are

   1. I have to buy most of them
   2. They leave to much garbage, so I prefer better solution.
4. Install Linux — it's not good practice to do double work.
5. Buy CD Drive — only for one installation?
6. Boot from PXE/TFTP — There's lack of NFS server from which I can mount root.
7. Buy Windows 2008 which has NFS server and can be used to mount root in FreeBSD  Boot process — only for one installation?
8. Install virtual machine such as VirtualBox, install FreeBSD here and write image to flash drive. VirtualBox have very bad USB support.
9. Buy virtual machine which works good with USB and you able to write image to flash drive under this — only for one installation?
10. Write my own program.

So, which software can I use to do this task?

PS: If you use Linux, want to write flash image under Windows XP x86 (I don't know why this software is broken, may be because x64 platform)

Please, look here, this is not question I ask: [How do I place a bootable ISO on an USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

**Edit:**
With latest Cygwin [version](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new1.7.html) which are "compatible with Window Vista/7" I always get following with unmounted drive (my system drive is PhysicalDrive2):

```
C:\Windows\system32>dd if=//./PhysicalDrive0 of=C:/mbr count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.003 seconds, 171 kB/s

C:\Windows\system32>dd if=c:/mbr of=//./PhysicalDrive0 count=1
dd: opening `//./PhysicalDrive0': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Which ones did you try?

Comment: dd, unetbootin. I haven't (and don't want to) try daemon tools, nero, acronis, etc - they spams into system a lot and I'll have to to cleanup it after.

Comment: what kind og image? .img or .iso?

Comment: I have both, but prefer to able to write any .img

Comment: Have you read [how to place bootable iso on a flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)? If so, please [edit] your question to explain what didn't work from that post, and I'll reopen your question. Otherwise, it's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I've read and I've tested all apps. They are not working under Windows 7 x64 and FreeBSD (Unetbootin makes perfect boots only for Linux)

Comment: I've updated my topic

Answer (score 4):

In Cygwin version 6 and above the dd command to write an ISO has changed:

```
dd if=path-to-file.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

where sdx is one of the drives:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

For example, to write a FreeBSD img file onto a USB memory stick:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

    8     0  78150744 sda
    8     1    102400 sda1
    8     2  51096576 sda2
    (...)
    8    48 976762584 sdd
    8    49 295185408 sdd1
    8    50 681573376 sdd2
    8    64   8093696 sde
    8    65   8093680 sde1

$ dd if=/cygdrive/l/FreeBSD-9.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/sde bs=10240 conv=sync
```

Also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media for alternative methods.

Comment: The `dd of=/dev/sdc` command immediately gave `dd: writing to '/dev/sdc': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Fixed the problem by unassigning the drive letter. Apparently, Windows doesn't talk nice to those trying to overwrite sectors underneath a mounted filesystem!

Comment: You can also run the Cygwin terminal with Administration privileges (e.g. Run as administrator)

Comment: R u kidding me? I _have_ to run as administrator, or I won't have direct access to disk!

Comment: Well, it's no different than Linux, isn't it? See the previous comment. You need admin rights if you don't want to bother with anassigning the drive letter. It's a Windows limitation, not Cygwin, hence Windows admin rights required.

Answer (score 2):

[`dd`](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd), what else.

```
dd if=foo.img of=\\.\F:
```

There's also [`flashnul`](http://shounen.ru/soft/flashnul/):

```
flashnul F: -L foo.img
```

Comment: it is outdated. It doesn't work in Windows 7 x64. Last update was at 2005-01-27 20:32-0800

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work". It does not use any features that could have been removed or changed. It *does*, however, need elevation ("Run as Administrator").

Comment: I've runned cmd under administrator, surely. This utilities don't want to write any data. I've do all as listed with no success. I've seen many good utilities which works fine in Windows XP and don't in Windows 7. Disk subsystem is one of part of incompatibility between W7 x64 and WXP x32.

Comment: Also I need to write everything include MBR

Comment: For example, I need write working FreeBSD release. Linux can be written with http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin but BSD not.

Comment: @Eir Nym Try with utilities from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). They might work. Also did you try with dd from mingw or cygwin (I'm not 100% sure that they actually have it). Also the Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications on windows should have working dd, so try it too.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448

Comment: NOT funny! lots of wasted time figuring out that it creates a file called `/cygdrive/c/.F:`

Answer (score 2):

Try [WINDOWS 7 USB/DVD DOWNLOAD TOOL](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)
As Eir Nym stated, this installs microsoft's bootloader, which you can user for any windows iso (I've used it to install windows 8)
For general purpose loader use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: it is one of tools you can use to install Windows 7. But I need low-level disk access such as dd(1). For example of image file you can use file filled with zero or random bytes to remove any data you have on USB.

Comment: +1 for digging up that link. Microsoft kept it hidden for a while.

Comment: @Eir Nym Did you try the utility? It's supposed to be able to copy correctly image to a flash drive including any special quirks.

Comment: Only with NT boot loader. I need BSD boot loader.

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been updated in a while, but [usb-imagewriter](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) does just what you need and definitely works with .img files and nearly any OS image I've tried (indeed, many alternative OSes recommend it).

Answer (score 0):

Cool. What an easy question.

Here is the solution: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

And it works. Believe me.

Comment: I hate Unetbootin because not every "bootable" flash drive I'll get, will boot.

Comment: @EirNym This depends on the machine your are trying to boot from. And not on machine you are building the flash drive.

Comment: Are you sure? On which things does it depends? I've tried these images with very different netbooks, laptops and PCs. from different manufactures.

Comment: ah, Linux will boot almost always, BSD not.

Comment: BIOS implementation, version, manufacturer; flash drive size, manufacturer; machine age, manufacturer