# How to make a ISO file out of a folder containing Windows setup files

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, usb, iso-image

I copied the Windows 8 CD to my HDD. I want to convert that folder to an ISO and use that to create a bootable USB.

Please tell me how I can make an ISO image out of that folder containing files.

This is my folder which I want to convert to a ISO file:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to use any disk burning program that supports creating an .iso file.  After you do that you can use the [program](http://superuser.com/questions/367935/how-to-make-a-usb-flash-drive-bootable-like-a-cd-made-from-an-iso?rq=1) of your choice to burn the .iso to the flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

To do that, at first you will need a ISO image creator tool. `PowerISO` can be a good choice as it's interface is easy and making bootable image using this software is straightforward.

Now follow the image to drag and drop files inside PowerISO and select `DVD 4.7G`.

[image]

You will see that it is showing `Non-bootable Image` as no boot configuration is added yet. Now to add boot configuration, go to `Action -> Boot -> Add boot information...`.

[image]

Then, in the dialog box click on the file icon beside `File` and go to the directory where your Windows 8 files are kept. Then follow the next image to select `All Files(*.*)` as the file type.

[image]

After that you will find a file named `etfsboot`. Select it and hit OK. Then you will see in lower left corner of PowerIso, now it is showing as Bootable Image, which means that you have successfully configured it as a bootable image. Now save the image file in your desired location and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Create ISO image is able by MagicISO or CDBurnerXP.

Bootable USB stick is able to create by [MS USB DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

OR you can use these [MS commands](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/07/26/create-bootable-usb-thumb-drive-key-using-diskpart-with-windows-8-media-to-install-windows-8-release-preview-or-other-operating-system.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Creating bootable USB using command prompt (`cmd.exe`).
Software such as Power ISO are often severely limited in terms of features in their free versions, so I wanted to use native windows tools to make bootable USB. I followed [MS commands](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/07/26/create-bootable-usb-thumb-drive-key-using-diskpart-with-windows-8-media-to-install-windows-8-release-preview-or-other-operating-system.aspx) link given by [@jerry1](https://superuser.com/a/736806/388501), with a few modifications of my own to create a Windows 11 bootable USB drive.

1. Insert a USB drive
2. open elevated command prompt (Run `cmd.exe` as administrator)
3. Run the following commands
4. `diskpart`
5. `list disk` Make sure you see the list of disks so that you dont select the wrong drive by mistake.
6. `select disk 1` Instead of 1 use the disk number for your USB drive
7. `clean` Remove partition table. Save data before this
8. `create partition primary` Create a new partition table
9. `select partition 1`
10. `format fs=fat32 quick label=w11` The MSDN link uses NTFS partition, fat32 worked for me.
11. `active` Mark the partition active. Some bootloaders use this flag to figure out which of the partitions contain OS
12. `exit` Exit diskpart
13. `cd D:\downloads\WINDOWS11E64V22154` Navigate to folder containing Windows setup files
14. `cd boot` Navigate to boot folder
15. `bootsect.exe /nt60 f: /mbr` Run bootsect command to write info to MBR. `/mbr` is for MBR partitioning type. If you see an error similar to `The update may be unreliable since ...` make sure the USB drive is not open in any explorer or cmd.exe window (details on MSDN link).

[image: cmd.exe commands]

16. Copy all files from setup folder to the USB drive. You can use explorer for this.

Directory structure of USB drive after copying files:

[image: Directory structure of USB drive after copying windows setup files]

On my system I had to turn off safe mode, and fast boot in BIOS. You may also have to enable legacy/compatibility mode in BIOS.

**References:**

1. MSDN: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/danstolts/create-bootable-usb-thumb-drive-key-using-diskpart-with-windows-8-media-to-install-windows-8-release-preview-or-other-operating-system
2. https://www.diskpart.com/articles/bootable-usb-windows-11-0001.html