# Creating bootable USB drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, bootloader, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

I'm wanting to install another OS on my network with no CD drive and wondering how to create a bootable ISO on a USB drive. Is there a trick to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick depends on what operating system.

If you're installing **Linux**, try the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

If you're installing **Windows**, try the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You should try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/easybcd/) (free). [Sample instructions](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Step-by-Step+Guide+to+Making+a+Bootable+Windows+Recovery+USB).