# Need help making a bootable portable USB hard drive. [Utility I need will only create bootable CDs or USB flash drives]

Tags: usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootloader, bootable-media, portable-harddrive

I've got a copy of [Spotmau's Bootsuite](http://www.spotmau.com/products/package/bootsuite.html) 2012, which is an utterly *fantastic* tool. It has completely replaced Bart PE for me, and I relied on BPE for YEARS.

Anyway, the issue I'm having is that the Bootsuite installer utility will only create bootable USB flash drives, or bootable CDs. The USB hard drive is detected as a hard drive instead of as a USB device, and as such I cannot use the included app to install to the USB HDD.

Is there a way of either copying the files from a bootable flash drive to a USB HDD and making that work, or of taking an .ISO of the bootable CD and using that to make the portable HD bootable?

The flash drives I've made of it are great as I can always have it with me [have 16GB dangling from my keychain. :) ], but my USB hard drive is FAR faster than any flash drive I have, so I'd like to be able to use that when I'm working out of my office or happen to have it with me.

Comment: possible dupe http://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive

Comment: My question is similar, but not the same. I'm trying to get a bootable .ISO installed to a USB HARD DRIVE, not a USB flash drive.

Comment: What oses are we talking about? Windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

unetbootin looks like just what you're looking for. Keep in mind it may not enable persistence

Comment: Tried that, it only shows my hard drives that are connected via SATA, or USB flash drives. For some reason my USB portable hard drives it doesn't support.

Comment: well if you know linux well enough you might be able to make it happen.you could try making a bootable flash drive and dd it to your usb hd :)

Answer (score 1):

Try an earlier version of unetbootin that supported showing all drive letters. 
Version 506 for example:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/506/

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin will surely do the trick for you if you are using any of the debian based operating 
systems to create a bootable HDD

> steps:
>
> 1)sudo apt-get install unetbootin
>
> 2)fire up unetbootin (you will need root access)
>
> 3)select your image file
>
> 4)select removable devices
>     tick the option that says "show all devices"
>
> 5)select device and start writing to it.

but unetbootin doesn't support this feature in windows (at least with newer versions).