# Is it possible to create bootable USB from "any" bootable ISO

Tags: usb, iso-image, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)

I know its possible for Windows or most other OS. But I am talking about general purpose utility software. I have an bootable ISO of rescue software and I want to make bootable USB out of it. So is it there any software that can turn "any" bootable ISO to bootable USB (say Pendrive).

Comment: I think this question is very interesting ... actually there are not boot loader with such possibility ( I think ). It will nice if grub let do it with any Iso ( also Osx ISO )

Answer (score 3):

Try this software: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net. Although it initially supports the listed distros, in [this section](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#other) it shows how to make it work with non-supported ones, which may well be the case of your recovery ISO (I can bet it is some kind of linux distro instead of Windows or some obscure OS).

If you use Windows instead, you can try this one too: http://rufus.akeo.ie. I never tried it, but I guess it should work.

Comment: I use unetbootin w/o a problem as well.

Comment: Can I create a USB for Acronis True Image rescue disk. I tried but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one !
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
It is the best for me because it is Multiboot USB Creator (Windows). That means you can store many Linux Distributions, Hiren Boot, and Windows Setup in a same place (USB Flash Drive).