# Replace Windows' drive format tool with Rufus

Tags: windows, format, rundll32.exe, shell32.dll, rufus

I recently came across the Super User question *[How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/#439832)* in my endeavour to find the easiest way to write the contents of an ISO image to a flash drive.

However, after finding the above, I started a mission to see if it would be possible (relatively easily) to replace the built-in Windows drive formatting tool (if one is the kind of person that only formats USB connected media day-to-day, with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

I got as far as:

1) Loading up an [elevated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.onlinevista.aspx#id0080001) [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) instance.

2) Finding that selecting "Format" from the right click context menu of a drive in My Computer, introduced a `dllhost.exe` instance to my running process (by clicking the bulls-eye, and hovering over the Format window), that runs `%systemroot%\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid:{7AA7790D-75D7-484B-98A1-3913D022091D}`:

[image]

3) Finding a registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{7aa7790d-75d7-484b-98a1-3913d022091d}` (and a identical HKCU one).

4) But, then, I have run into a roadblock with how to launch "...`%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-28702`" found in the string value titled `LocalizedString`. I have tried `rulldll32 shell32.dll -28702` & `rulldll32 shell32.dll,-28702` & `rulldll32 shell32.dll,"-28702"` , and also can't seem to find any information on launching (what the) 28702 (is, ?a offset?) online.

How can I do step 4, and also share their specific-to-this-idea and/or general knowledge/experience about replacing /by passing (what I assume is) functions in shell32.dll?

*NOTE*: I believe there is a way of changing the *Drive* right-click context menu to change what "Format" launches, but (while this may be easier) is not how I would like to achieve the above.