# Create a bootable hard disk drive containing multiple OS

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, bootable-media

I have a portable 1 TB hard disk drive. It contain various folders and it also contain the setup for windows 7 x86 and x64. I also plan to download Ubuntu and backtract later. 
I also have other files on this drive.

I want to make the hard disk bootable so that I can install any OS that I want through USB.
I will put installation files in folders for e.g Windows 7 x86 folder, Windows 7 x64 and Backtract folder.

When I boot the hard drive, a menu should appear and ask me with OS I want to install.

I know this can be done by burning the individual OS to different DVD and then boot from DVD but its not what I want to achieve here.

Comment: I can conceivably think of a program that runs first and then links itself to the various setups. Assuming the setups aren't hardlinked to the media, it shouldn't be a (big) problem.

Comment: That exactly want i am looking for....but what you mean by hardlinked

Comment: Consider that the OS installation disks are usually made to boot from a single drive, so you first need to trick the underlying system with that program. I know of some utilities that "shrink" or allow you to make your own Windows installation disk, but I've never heard of one that allowed to do this for multiple.
If a program existed that, at boot, allowed you to choose an ISO file to boot from, that would be an acceptable solution to your problem.

Comment: With a quick search, maybe [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) ([SU link](http://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)) may be what you were looking for, although I don't know if it allows to dual-boot.

Comment: Unetbootin reformat the HDD as far as i know but i want a solution that don't force reformat as i have other dta on it

Comment: The other solution I could find was to use a bootloader like GRUB and then boot from it the ISO files, as described on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847)

Answer (score 0):

Try using YUMI, or Sardu.

I have been using them for quite a while now, (specially Sardu, I use it almost everyday since 2011)

Comment: why do you suggest YUMI or Sardu? what are they?