# Windows 10 USB Installer refuses to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, dell-optiplex, windows-insider

I've decided to upgrade to Windows 10 on my Dell Optiplex 760, but the problem is when I boot from the USB, nothing happens. This is also the same on my laptop which is where I downloaded the iso from [Microsoft's Insider Build page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced), I have tried both arch's (x86 and x64) and both won't boot from my desktop. What should I do?

Specs:

Dell Optiplex 760

Intel Core2 Duo (64 Bit Processor)

nVidia GeForce 210 1GB DDR3

2GB DDR2 RAM

Intel Virtulisation Technology (VT-d / VT-x)

CD/DVD RW Drive

Comment: Did you specifically boot from the USB?

Comment: Yes, I press F12 and select "USB" from the boot list, it is even set in the bios to boot first.

Comment: how did you put Windows on the USB?

Comment: I use a trusted software called "Rufus" (https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: As Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool will not detect my USB

Comment: Hmm. That should've worked. When you choose the USB option, what happens? Also, did you burn the USB for GPT or MBR?

Comment: Im not quite sure, let me try again with the x64 iso

Comment: so I selected the ISO file and the partition option instantly goes to GPT for UEFI

Comment: Try telling it to use MBR for BIOS

Comment: Ok I have done that and its flashing it at the moment

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/q/1063220/39364

Answer (score -1):

Try using WinToUSB to create a Windows installation USB falsh drive to install Windows 10/8/7, with this free software you don't need to specify the partition scheme and file system type.

[How to create a Windows installation USB flash drive with BIOS and UEFI support?](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en_US/How-to-create-bootable-Windows-installation-USB.html)

Comment: WintoUSB makes a Windows TO GO USB, basically Windows 10 running on a USB

Comment: WinToUSB has released a new feature called "Windows Installation USB Creator" which allows you to create a Windows installation USB flash drive with BIOS and UEFI support.

Answer (score -1):

Use RUFUS to make bootable USB drive for Windows. Steps can be found here- [Using RUFUS](http://www.penguincoders.net/2015/05/make-bootable-pen-drive-from-iso-image-in-windows.html) and Bootable pen drive can also be made without any software. Follow these steps- [Without any software](http://www.penguincoders.net/2015/12/create-bootable-usb-drive-without-software-windows-installation.html)

Comment: That's what I am using

Comment: Can you add details on how to make without software so superuser has the information and incase link breaks and use the link as support to your information-thanks