# How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, liveusb

I have erased the entire HDD and I'm trying to install a dual boot of both Ubuntu and Windows.

1. First I made one bootable USB drive using an Ubuntu .iso file. I set the boot order in BIOS correctly. After restarting my machine, I correctly sees setup steps for Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu successfully.
2. On the second step, I made another bootable USB drive using a Windows 7 .iso file. I set the boot order correctly. When I restarted my machine, I couldn't see anything but *Missing Operating System*. Then Ubuntu starts to boot and load.

Can anyone help me here to solve this issue of installing Windows?

Comment: How exactly did you make "another USB drive boot-able using windows 7 .iso file"? Ubuntu iso is deliberately built to support booting from USB (after you `dd` the iso to it), as well as from CD/DVD (after you burn it). I don't think Windows 7 iso is equally smart. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/274809/432690) is what I'm talking about. What tool did you use? Also: in my opinion the less troublesome order would be to install Windows first, Linux last.

Comment: I used Unetbootin software to make usb drive bootable using windows .iso file.
It slightly remember it has worked for me in past.. However please suggest if i should another effective software for making usb windows boot-able

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't have Windows 7 installed yet, you can also create a bootable USB flash drive for installing Windows 7 from Ubuntu using a USB flash drive. WoeUSB is a tool for creating a bootable USB flash drive used for installing Windows. Native UEFI booting is supported for Windows 7 and later images. WoeUSB is an updated fork of the WinUSB project.

Some third-party installers feature Windows installation images (`/sources/install.wim`) greater than 4GB making FAT32 as target filesystem impossible. NTFS filesystem support has been added to WoeUSB 3.0.0 and later.

#### Installation

To install WoeUSB (GUI+CLI) in Ubuntu 14.04/16.04/17.10-20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install woeusb
```

This will install the WoeUSB graphical interface and the WoeUSB command line tool. WoeUSB supports both UEFI and BIOS for FAT32/NTFS/ExFAT USB flash drives.

To install the WoeUSB command line tool snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --edge woe-usb  
sudo snap connect woe-usb:removable-media
```

To launch the woe-usb snap package command line tool run the following command:

```
/snap/bin/woe-usb.woeusb
```

If you get a `permission denied` error click the *Permissions* button on the *woe-usb* screen in Ubuntu Software and toggle the permissions options from OFF to ON as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: woe-usb Permissions]

The WoeUSB GUI is easier to use than the WoeUSB command line tool. Click the radio button to the left of where it says *From a disk image (iso)*, browse to the location of the Windows .iso file, under *Target device* select a USB flash drive, open Disks application and check that the Device name in Disks matches the Target device in WoeUSB (it should be something like /dev/sd**X** where **X** is a letter of the alphabet), and click the *Install* button to install to create a bootable Windows installation media on the USB flash drive.

[image]

[Windows USB drive from Ubuntu failing repeatedly](https://askubuntu.com/a/1244405/)
[WoeUSB Issues](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243565/)

Answer (score 2):

1. If using rufus:

   - Make sure partition scheme is MBR (for BIOS or UEFI)
   - NTFS file sytem

Like as shown below

[image]

2. Probably the better to create a Windows (7) bootable disk, is using the tool from **Microsoft**  - [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)

or directly from codeplex: [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://wudt.codeplex.com)

The second option has no hassle as the setup is straightforward needing no extra configurations as with rufus.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [onetransistor.blogspot.co.uk](https://onetransistor.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html)

> Before starting, let's mention that there are two types of boot
> methods. There is the MBR code type where the bootable executable is
> stored in a reserved section at the beginning of the storage device.
> And there is the EFI type, where the boot loader executable file is
> stored at a standard path in an FAT32 filesystem.
>
> You must decide in advance what you will use. There are some variables
> for each boot type. **If you have no idea what to use, the most common
> setup that works with unmodified Windows sources, is `msdos` partition
> table with `fat32` filesystem and flag the partition with `boot`**. In this
> way you will get both an MBR and UEFI bootable drive.
>
> [image: USB Boot flags MBR/UEFI mods/gpt]
>
> 1. **Format USB drive**
>
> Plug in your USB flashdrive and start GParted.
> Select the USB drive and unmount it.
> You must re-create the partition table by going to the Device menu
> then select Create Partition Table. Choose `msdos` (or `gpt` if you want
> an UEFI only bootable drive) and click Apply.
> Right click the unallocated space and select New. Make a primary NTFS or FAT32
> partition and give it a label too. The label must be as strange as possible
> because the bootloader will identify the bootable partition.
>
> If you have a `install.wim` larger than 4 GB you should definitely go for NTFS.
>
> Apply all pending operation from Edit menu - Apply all operations. Right
> click the partition and choose Manage flags. If you chose the `msdos`
> partition table tick `boot`. If you chose the `gpt` partition table, `msftdata`
> should already be checked.
>
> 2. **Copy Windows files**
>
> Quit GParted and use the file manager to copy all files from Windows ISO to USB
> stick. Mount the ISO using Open with - Disk Image Mounter. After the copy
> process is finished, look in the USB root folder for the boot directory.
> If it is uppercase, rename it to lowercase.
>
> 3. **Make it bootable**
>
> If you used NTFS filesystem and MSDOS table, only method A is
> available. If you used FAT32 and MSDOS table, you can apply method A,
> B or both. If you used GPT partition table, only method B should be
> followed.
>
> - **A. MBR bootable**
>
> GRUB will be used for that. Open a Terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/<username>/<drive_label>/boot" /dev/sdX
> ```
>
> Replace:
>
> - `/media/<username>/<drive_label>` with the path where USB drive is mounted
> - `/dev/sdX` with the USB drive, not the partition (e.g. `/dev/sdb`)
>
> Now, create a text file and write the following in it:
>
> ```
> default=1  
> timeout=15
> color_normal=light-cyan/dark-gray
> menu_color_normal=black/light-cyan
> menu_color_highlight=white/black
>  
> menuentry "Start Windows Installation" {
>     insmod ntfs
>     insmod search_label
>     search --no-floppy --set=root --label <USB_drive_label> --hint hd0,msdos1
>     ntldr /bootmgr
>     boot
> }
>
> menuentry "Boot from the first hard drive" {
>     insmod ntfs
>     insmod chain
>     insmod part_msdos
>     insmod part_gpt
>     set root=(hd1)
>     chainloader +1
>     boot
> }
> ```
>
> Replace `<USB_drive_label>` with the label you gave it when you formatted the
> drive (you can place it between quotes if it contains a space, although it is
> not recommended to use spaces in drive label). Save the file as grub.cfg and
> put it on the USB drive in the boot/grub folder.
> That's it. The USB drive is now bootable from BIOS and can be used to
> install Windows on your PC. The first time you boot from it in MBR
> BIOS or CSM mode select `Start Windows Installation`.
>
> - **B. UEFI bootable**
>
> Not all Windows versions are supported. Windows 7 on 64 bits, Windows
> 8 and newer versions should work.
>
> After the copy process is finished, look in the USB root folder for
> the efi/boot directory. If there's a bootx64.efi or bootia32.efi file
> there, then you're done. You can boot from your USB in UEFI mode.
>
> If the OS you are making a bootable USB for is Windows 7, browse the
> efi/microsoft folder and copy the entire boot folder from this path
> one level up in the efi folder. Merge folders if boot already exists.
>
> Here is what to do if you don't have the bootx64.efi file in efi/boot
> folder. Browse the mounted Windows ISO image into the sources folder.
> Open install.wim (or install.esd) with your archive manager (you will
> need 7z installed). Go to the path ./1/Windows/Boot/EFI and extract
> the file bootmgfw.efi anywhere you want. Rename it to bootx64.efi and
> put it on the USB drive, in the efi/boot folder. If you can't find
> bootmgfw.efi in install.wim then you probably have a 32 bit Windows
> ISO or other types of images (recovery disks, upgrade versions).
>
> You can now boot from your USB in UEFI mode.

I quote the [original website](https://onetransistor.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) for reliability, But the website is way better in style and details, So use it unless you force not to.

Comment: Please see comments inline
For 1st point, I do not know much about MBR/GPT setting
For 2nd point, I already tried formatting disk with FAT32 and NTFS; unfortunately nothing works
For point 3, lets say if booting software has some issue, then how it made ubuntu bootable correctly?
For point 4, same USB was tested for ubuntu; works fine.

Comment: Try these if you can http://www.wintobootic.com/  And https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: It looks like both of these softwares are windows supported; unfortunately i have only Ubuntu in hand. Do we have any Ubuntu compatible software for making windows boot-able USB?

Comment: So please follow this https://onetransistor.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html And https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Comment: tell me what was wrong so i can complete my answer so others can use it

Comment: I followed https://onetransistor.blogspot.in/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html, made USB MBR bootable using msdos partition table and followed steps as per guideline..
It prompted me to install windows from USB.